# MOXy unmarhsalling empty content exception

Tags: moxy

Below is exception when I passed empty (string length is zero) any payload to pass server rest resource. at the time i got below exception. please guide me to right direction. how our requirements we are generate the JSON from JAXB annotated data class.

```
failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token EOF at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0), Expected Tokens [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:660) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.rest.common.utils.CustomJSONProvider.readFrom(CustomJSONProvider.java:83) [classes:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:105) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.read(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:63) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.proceed(MessageBodyReaderContextImpl.java:108) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:169) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:136) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:159) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.rest.common.rs.filter.RestWSFilter.doFilter(RestWSFilter.java:31) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.rest.common.rs.filter.RestSecurityAuthFilter$1.run(RestSecurityAuthFilter.java:66) [classes:]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.rest.common.rs.filter.RestSecurityAuthFilter$1.run(RestSecurityAuthFilter.java:59) [classes:]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.security.authn.util.JBossRunAs.runAs(JBossRunAs.java:127) [platform-core.jar:]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.security.authn.util.RunAsUtil.runWithSubject(RunAsUtil.java:37) [platform-core.jar:]
    at com.cisco.sdp.core.rest.common.rs.filter.RestSecurityAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(RestSecurityAuthFilter.java:58) [classes:]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:131) [spring-security-oauth2-1.0.3.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80-ea]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token EOF at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0), Expected Tokens [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.handleXMLMarshalException(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:1053) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:339) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:612) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    ... 65 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token EOF at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0), Expected Tokens [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.unmarshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:120) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:145) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:978) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:425) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:375) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:708) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:631) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:337) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Invalid token EOF at (line no=1, column no=1, offset=0), Expected Tokens [CURLYOPEN, SQUAREOPEN]
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$Context.getTransition(JsonParserImpl.java:266) [javax.json-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl$StateIterator.next(JsonParserImpl.java:184) [javax.json-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonParserImpl.next(JsonParserImpl.java:151) [javax.json-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.read(JsonReaderImpl.java:87) [javax.json-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.json.JsonStructureReader.parse(JsonStructureReader.java:137) [eclipselink.jar:2.6.0.v20141224-924f6b4]
    ... 72 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I have opened the following bug for this issue:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457166